# Angular 6, Subscribe and return Observable<boolean>

Tags: angular, observable

I'm new to Angular here, and training in Angular 6 with .Net Core.
I had this working earlier in the week, and I'm not sure where I broke it.
I wrote a authentication service that works, it calls the controller and returns the user, but in the component that calls the service, I can't get the subscribe to call the router.navigate. 
I just don't completely understand how to use Observable, or if I even need it here. It was working fine until I added the localStorage and wrote cookies.

I tried removing the new stuff I added, but no change. the component won't process the result to navigate. On Subscribe, I had result `.subscribe(_result => this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard'])` but got a typescript error result is of type . So I removed it.

My Signin Component, and the next block is my Auth.Service that makes the http.post call.

```
onSubmit() {

    this.authService.Authenticate(this.model)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
        _data => {                
            this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard'])
        },
        error => {
            console.log('Authentication process failed')
            this.model.Error = error;
            this.authFailure = true;
        }
    );

}

    Authenticate(signIn: SignIn) {

    let authenticateUrl = this.configuration.Server + 'api/auth/Authenticate';
    const toSignIn = JSON.stringify(signIn);

    return this.http.post<SignIn>(authenticateUrl, toSignIn, { headers: this.headers })
        .pipe(
            map(result => {
            if (result && result.Token) { 
                // Store user details and the jwt token
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken', result.Token);
                localStorage.setItem('userName', result.Username);
                localStorage.setItem('name', result.Firstname + ' ' + result.Lastname);
                this.authCookie.writeAuthCookies(result);                    
            }
            return result;
        })
    );
}

canActivate(_next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if (this.cookieAuth.readTokenOrCookie() === false) {

        // Redirect the request to signIn
        this.router.navigate(['/home/signin'], { queryParams: { return: state.url } });
        return false;
    }

    return true;        
}
```

Comment: You are not returning anything outside `if` condition. So when `if` condition fails, then nothing will be returned. You may try adding `return false;` outside `if`. This should have resulted you compiler error as well.

Answer (score 1):

You havn't handled the else block inside auth service and why we need pipe(first())?

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log('Calling Authentication Service');
    this.authService.Authenticate(this.model)
      .subscribe((valid) => this._router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']),
        _error => {
          console.log('Authentication process failed')
          this.model.Error = 'Authentication Failed';
          this.authFailure = true;
        }
      );

    Authenticate(signIn: SignIn): Observable < boolean > {
      let authenticateUrl = this.configuration.Server + 'api/auth/Authenticate';
      const toSignIn = JSON.stringify(signIn);
      return this.http.post < SignIn > (authenticateUrl, toSignIn, {
          headers: this.headers
        })
        .pipe(
          map(result => {
            if (result && result.Token) {
              console.log('AuthService, We have a valid response and token');
              // Store user details and the jwt token
              localStorage.setItem('accessToken', result.Token);
              localStorage.setItem('userName', result.Username);
              localStorage.setItem('name', result.Firstname + ' ' + result.Lastname);
              this.authCookie.writeAuthCookies(result);

              // For Debuging purposes
              console.log('Authenticate Complete, promise Observable');
              return true;
            }else{
              return false;
            }
          }),
          catchError((err, caught) => {
            return Observable.throw(new Error('App Error'));
          })
        );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

My Bad, it was working correctly, but the navigate was so fast, I didn't see it. So it navigated to dashboard, but my authGuard denied the request and redirected back to signin, so it looked like nothing happen.

[Solved], and I have clearer insight into how Observable works.